# Highlighting linux command in terminal

Tags: linux

I would like to highlight my linux commands on the terminal without using any extensions.

Problem statement:

```
echo "hi"
ls xyz
```

Requirement:

once i complete the command , it recognises this as a linux command and gives a color to it like echo and ls will be displayed in green color.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Some shells can do this. Should we recommend a shell? Or are you seeking solutions for some specific shell? What shell then?

Answer (score 3):

You have some options for that. Among them:

- Use `fish` as your shell. Install it and check if it does what yo want.
- add a layer on top of `bash`, like [`ble.sh`](https://github.com/akinomyoga/ble.sh). You can check their [demo video](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wiki/akinomyoga/ble.sh/images/trial1.gif) to see if that's what you want.

Both will do syntax highlighting and command recognition. But they are not the only ones (you can also get `zsh` to do that, for example).